# How to eliminate the bullets in MailChimp ul

Tags: css, visual-composer

I'm using either VC or WPBakery on various sites where I have embedded a MailChimp sign-up form. On all of the sites blue bullets appear underneath the checkboxes. MailChimp support has no idea why. I've tried many variations of CSS to get rid of them to no avail, including:

```
list-style:none !important;
list-style-type:none !important;
```

This doesn't work. Here's one site (the simplest VC site with no extraneous coding): http://livingbythestream.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of a :before on all of your fields. You can use the solution of Johannes above, or you could hide the :before completely since it is not being used anymore.

I have tested the code below on your website and seems to be working great:

```
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group.input-group ul li:before {
    display: none;
}
```

If thats not enough, you can use the !important to overwrite other existing css:

```
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group.input-group ul li:before {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS rule in your code that adds a bullet as a `:before` pseudo element.

Its selector is: `.comment-content ul > li::before, .entry-content ul > li::before { ... }`

So you could either erase that (if it lets you do that), or you could add another rule like this:

```
.comment-content ul > li::before, .entry-content ul > li::before {
  content: none;
}
```

If that's not enough, you might also add `!important` after `none`